# Mounting an old JBOD array with two disks DOS formatted

Tags: linux, command-line, disk, fdisk, data

I have a couple of 500GB disks with data inside that I would like to get back. The two disks were mounted inside a Lacie disk, part of a JBOD array and formatted FAT32.

I don't have the external disk electronics anymore, but I have an HP microserver, so I'm trying to temporarily recreate the JBOD array just to get the files, but it seems to fail recognizing one of the disks (sdb). The two disks are mounted inside the microserver.

First of all when I launch lsblk I can't see any partition in it, so I can't mount it:

```
nas:~ # lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     2M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    64M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda4   8:4    0 463,7G  0 part /mnt3/joe/backup_OMV
                                 /mnt2/home
                                 /mnt2/ROOT
                                 /opt
                                 /boot/grub2/i386-pc
                                 /home
                                 /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi
                                 /var
                                 /root
                                 /usr/local
                                 /tmp
                                 /srv
                                 /.snapshots
                                 /
sdb      8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465,8G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 465,8G  0 disk
```

Then I tried with fdisk to see which filesystem was on the disk. Nothing was showed off:

```
nas:~ # fdisk /dev/sdc -l
Disk /dev/sdc: 465,76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG HD501LJ 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

As you see the sdb disk was showed correctly (and if I mount it it gets mounted):

```
nas:~ # fdisk /dev/sdb -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 465,76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG HD501LJ 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0001f12c

Dispositivo Avvio Start       Fine    Settori   Size Id Tipo
/dev/sdb1   *        63 1953536129 1953536067 931,5G  b W95 FAT32
```

I've also tried to follow this guide: https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/How_can_I_recover_data_from_my_DiskStation_using_a_PC, but I'm stuck at this command:

```
nas:~ #  mdadm -AsfR && vgchange -ay 
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

Maybe it's a dumb question, but am I missing something? Is there a way to mount the JBOD array without specifying the disk (sdc) partition?

Comment: Do not `mount` sdb1, the partition table on `sdb` is for the whole JBOD. Wait for a good answer to appear or for a duplicate to be found (I'm on it).

Comment: I've just looked at the sdb dimension.. it seems to be extended to the whole JBOD array. Thank you for noticing it.

Comment: See this answer of mine: [*Can I rebuild a JBOD?*](https://superuser.com/a/1212521/432690)

Comment: The procedure with `dmsetup` from the link should work for you. I believe a simpler alternative is `mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=linear --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc`, but I have no experience with `mdadm` and I haven't tested.

Comment: I've launched the cat command 10 minutes ago, I think I'll wait for the image.raw to be completed first. Meanwhile thanks for the answer... I wasn't unable to find your answer "Can I rebuild a JBOD?", sorry for my noobness... I'll post updates in any case. Thank you for now.

Comment: Okk, I'm almost there. I've created image.raw, but none of the procedures (mounting the image or mounting the disks) is working right now.

I follow the procedure, then...
`nas:~ # echo "0 $M striped 2 256 /dev/sda 0 /dev/sdb 0" | dmsetup create mydevice`
`device-mapper: create ioctl on mydevice  failed: Device or resource busy`
`Command failed.`

Comment: (1) If mounting `sdb1` "worked" and if you concatenated in the right order, mounting the resulting image (with right `offset`) should also work. (2) You wrote it was JBOD. Why did you try `striped` then?

Comment: I gave up on mounting the two disks, I just mounted the raw image.

First I had to find out the start of the first partition with `fdisk -l image.raw`

Then i lauched the `mount` command with this arguments to mount it: `mount -t vfat -o loop,offset=$((63 * 512 ))  image.raw /mnt4/`

So the problem is solved, but I still can't access some directories stored in it... here's the output of `ls -l`:
`ls: cannot access 'Documenti': Errore di input/output
d?????????  ? ?    ?             ?            ? Documenti`

Seems that it can't even read the owner, the size, the date, permissions.